# Open ت and tied ة does both ت indicates at the end of the word that the word is feminine in arabic linguistics?

Tags: historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, arabic, word-formation

If a word ends with open ت or tied ة does both ت indicates at the end of the word that the word is feminine in arabic linguistics like ٱللَّتَ feminine form of word Allah in Quran 53:19?

Comment: "Indicate" is vague. Do you mean "absolutely prove", or "suggests the likelihood"?

Comment: Your question might be well received on Islam.SE

Comment: absolutely prove :)

Comment: I don't think you can "absolutely prove" anything ت

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `/t/` suffix makes a noun feminine in many Afro-Asiatic languages. However, in many of these languages (including Arabic), it's gotten lenited over time, and is now pronounced as `[h]` or silent: زَوْجَة `/zawɟat/` `[zawɟah]` "wife". When a suffix is added, the pronunciation is still `[t]`: زَوْجَتيِ `/zawɟatiː/` `[zawɟatiː]` "my wife"—the lenition only happens word-finally. So in Arabic, *only* when it's word-final, this `/t/` is written with the glyph for `/h/` plus the dots of `/t/`, showing both the underlying phoneme and its pronunciation.

However, in Arabic, this lenition happened only after `/a/`: if there wasn't an `/a/`, like in أُخْت `/ʔukt/` `[ʔukt]` "sister", the `/t/` remained `[t]`, and is written with the normal glyph for `/t/`. So one hypothesis about *'Allat* is that it was previously pronounced `/ʔalilaːt/` (based on a transcription in Herodotus), with a long `/aː/`, which blocked the lenition, and that this archaic pronunciation persisted until after the lenition stopped being productive.

Alternately, the word may have fossilized before the lenition happened, or the `[t]` pronunciation might have been kept specifically to keep it from becoming homophonous with *'Allah*. Or it may have come from an unrelated root L-T-T "knead". I'm not sure if there's a scholarly consensus on which of these is right. But there are definitely feminine nouns with a normal *ta* at the end, and I believe *'Allat* is definitely grammatically feminine (based on agreement), so I wouldn't read too much into it.

Comment: Thank you so very much brother for this info now i understand that if a word ends at ت or ة both indicates that the word is feminine! right brother? :)

Comment: @BilalKhan Often yes, but not always. Unrelated words can also end in `/t/` for unrelated reasons.

Answer (score 0):

ت and ة can appear at the end of a word for a number of reasons in Arabic (presumably classical Arabic is the real scope of the question). An example of a non-feminine is كتبت "I wrote". Hence you need to also include the provision that the text is fully vocalized: كَتَبْتُ. But you also have to exclude the imperative of any root ending in /t/, or modern nouns like البزموت. As far as I know, بُعُولَة "husbands" is a masculine (plural) noun and خَلِيفَة "caliph" is masculine singular. [This article](http://corpus.quran.com/documentation/gender.jsp) discusses criteria for gender assignment in Quranic Arabic, which is not trivial.